# how to concatenate string with two different delimiters with xsl

Tags: string, xslt, concatenation, delimiter

I have a XML

```
<main>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <COMPONENT_SID>100</COMPONENT_SID>
    <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <COMPONENT_SID>200</COMPONENT_SID>
    <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <COMPONENT_SID>400</COMPONENT_SID>
    <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <COMPONENT_SID>10</COMPONENT_SID>
    <GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <COMPONENT_SID>20</COMPONENT_SID>
    <GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <COMPONENT_SID>2</COMPONENT_SID>
    <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <COMPONENT_SID>4</COMPONENT_SID>
    <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <COMPONENT_SID>8</COMPONENT_SID>
    <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  <DATA_RECORD>
    <COMPONENT_SID>16</COMPONENT_SID>
    <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
  </DATA_RECORD>
  </main>
```

I would like to use xsl to parse into another XML. The output would be

```
<comp value="100,200,400|10,20|2,4,8,16"/>
```

where the component_sids belonged to different group_id are separated by "|" . The component_sids belonged to the same group id should be concatenated with ",". I used the following xsl

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
          <xsl:element name="comp">
             <xsl:attribute name="value">
                 <xsl:call-template name="join"> 
                        <xsl:with-param name="list" select="//DATA_RECORD[GROUP_ID=1]/COMPONENT_SID" /> 
                        <xsl:with-param name="separator" select="','" />                                             
                  </xsl:call-template> 
              </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template name="join"> 
    <xsl:param name="list" /> 
    <xsl:param name="separator"/>     
    <xsl:for-each select="$list"> 
      <xsl:value-of select="." /> 
      <xsl:if test="position() != last()"> 
        <xsl:value-of select="$separator" />         
      </xsl:if> 
    </xsl:for-each> 
  </xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The result is

```
<comp value="100,200,400"/>
```

But I could not figured out how to separate other groups of component_sid with "|". Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete, simple, short and easy solution. Explanation is also provided.

Comment: I also added an XSLT 2.0 solution which is twice as short as the XSLT 1.0 solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSLT 2.0 solution can be shortened further to:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vResult">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*/*" group-by="GROUP_ID">
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">|</xsl:if>
    <xsl:value-of select="current-group()/COMPONENT_SID" separator=","/>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:variable>

  <comp value="{$vResult}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I. XSLT 1.0 solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:key name="kRecByGrId" match="DATA_RECORD"
                            use="GROUP_ID"/>

 <xsl:variable name="vGrIds" select=
 "/*/DATA_RECORD
      [generate-id()
      =
       generate-id(key('kRecByGrId', GROUP_ID)[1])
       ]
        /GROUP_ID
 "/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="vResult">
       <xsl:for-each select="$vGrIds">
        <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">|</xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select=
          "key('kRecByGrId', .)/COMPONENT_SID"/>
       </xsl:for-each>
     </xsl:variable>

     <comp value="{$vResult}"/>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="COMPONENT_SID">
      <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">,</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<main>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_SID>100</COMPONENT_SID>
        <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
    </DATA_RECORD>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_SID>200</COMPONENT_SID>
        <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
    </DATA_RECORD>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_SID>400</COMPONENT_SID>
        <GROUP_ID>1</GROUP_ID>
    </DATA_RECORD>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_SID>10</COMPONENT_SID>
        <GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
    </DATA_RECORD>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_SID>20</COMPONENT_SID>
        <GROUP_ID>2</GROUP_ID>
    </DATA_RECORD>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_SID>2</COMPONENT_SID>
        <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
    </DATA_RECORD>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_SID>4</COMPONENT_SID>
        <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
    </DATA_RECORD>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_SID>8</COMPONENT_SID>
        <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
    </DATA_RECORD>
    <DATA_RECORD>
        <COMPONENT_SID>16</COMPONENT_SID>
        <GROUP_ID>3</GROUP_ID>
    </DATA_RECORD>
</main>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<comp value="100,200,400|10,20|2,4,8,16"/>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **Muenchian method for grouping** -- to find all distinct values of `GROUP_ID` .
2. **Simple logic to precede an item (or group) with a delimiter**, whenever this item (or group) isn't the first.

**II. XSLT 2.0 Solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:variable name="vResult">
   <xsl:for-each-group select="*/*" group-by="GROUP_ID">
    <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">|</xsl:if>
    <xsl:for-each select="current-group()/COMPONENT_SID">
      <xsl:if test="not(position()=1)">,</xsl:if>
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:for-each-group>
  </xsl:variable>

     <comp value="{$vResult}"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied to the same XML document (above), again the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<comp value="100,200,400|10,20|2,4,8,16"/>
```

**Explanation**:

1. Use of `<xsl:for-each-group>`
2. Use of `current-group()`
3. The same simple logic for preceding each item (or group), which isn't the first, with the respective delimiter.

Comment: @Richard, glad my answer was useful. Please, don't forget to accept the best answer (Hint: just click on the check-mark next to the answer).